# How to get the marathi unicode front from json and display on android

Tags: php, android, json

I have marathi data stored in mysql database and want to display in android using json, I am able to get the English data, but if trying to get the marathi it displays "?????" even when i print json on browser it also shows "????"
i am using php for defining web service.

My json Output:

[{"heading":"??? ???? ","details":"??? ???? ???? ??????????? ??? ?? ????? ?????????? ???? ???????? ??????? ??????? ???? ?? ??????? ???? ????? ??? ?????????? ????? ?? ?????????? ??? ??? ??????????? ??????????? ? ???????????? ?? ???. ????? ????????? ????? ?????? ????? ?????????? ?????? ??"}]

values are coming to android but displaying like "???????"

[image]

how to do it??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using utf8 in your database tables & php database connection (you have to run "SET NAMES utf8" after connecting to mysql)?

If so, does it work correctly in desktop browser? If it does, I suppose you have to use different font, if not, then you have to fix your database/connection encoding

Comment: Yes i have used utf8 in database table but how to use utf8 for php database connection and how to run this SET NAMES utf8??

Comment: you have to place mysql_query("SET NAMES utf8"); right after mysql_connect function where you create the db connection

Comment: ok Thnak you michail i will try.. thanks for so quick response

Comment: Also use what Suhail Mehta suggested, in PHP you can do it like this: header("Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8"); You have to place it before all output

Answer (score 0):

```
httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
```

Set the content-type in header of your response as utf-8